# Excluding Uppercase letter from words

Tags: python, regex

Here is regex to exclude all uppercase from words but it does not work"

```
import re
s = 'Wd+ Si# Sd*'
slower=''.join(re.findall('([a-z])[-#]*',s))
print slower
```

When I checked on http://www.regexr.com/ it works fine but in program it gives only lowercase characters.

In above example it should give output

`d+` , `i#` , and `d*`

Comment: Can you show an example input and expected output?

Comment: @Cyber: thanks for interest. I already gave

Comment: An alternative approach without regex: `from string import ascii_uppercase; filter(lambda x: x not in ascii_uppercase, s)`

Comment: Why use regex for this?  Just  `''.join(x for x in s if not x.isupper())`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [str.translate](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_translate.htm)

```
s = 'Wd+ Si# Sd*'
import string

print(s.translate(None,string.uppercase))
d+ i# d*
```

Quite a bit faster than a regex and faster than using join:

```
In [29]: import re    
In [30]: s = 'Wd+ Si# Sd*'
In [31]: timeit ''.join(re.findall('[^A-Z]', s))
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.23 µs per loop

In [32]: import string    
In [33]: timeit s.translate(None,string.uppercase)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 388 ns per loop


In [38]: timeit ''.join([i for i in s if i not in ascii_uppercase])
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.07 µs per loop
```

Comment: read the question!  he wants the `slower` way to do this ... ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use the hat `^` to exclude all of the uppercase letters `[A-Z]`:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'Wd+ Si# Sd*'
>>> ''.join(re.findall('[^A-Z]', s))
'd+ i# d*'
```

---

Only instead of using `join` with `re.search`, use `re.sub`- it's simpler:

```
>>> re.sub('[A-Z]', '', s)  # No '^' here as we want to find upper-case to replace.
'd+ i# d*'
```

Answer (score 2):

why not replace all `[A-Z]`  with empty string?

```
In [3]: re.sub('[A-Z]','','Wd+ Si# Sd*')                       
Out[3]: 'd+ i# d*'
```

if you want to filter spaces/tab... out, you just add `\s`:

```
In [5]: re.sub('[A-Z\s]','','Wd+ Si# Sd*')
Out[5]: 'd+i#d*'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that uses a generator expression instead of a regex.

```
>>> from string import ascii_uppercase
>>> s = 'Wd+ Si# Sd*'
>>> uppers = set(ascii_uppercase)
>>> ''.join(i for i in s if i not in uppers)
'd+ i# d*'
```

Comment: you should use a list comp when using join

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes... they are slightly faster, however, the greatest efficiency problem here will be the `not in ascii_uppercase`

Comment: @JonClements true, what would you propose instead?

Comment: Good call, I swapped out the list for a set for quicker lookups.